# what does "auto-fit pages" do in the browser

Tags: browser

In the stock Android browser, what exactly does "auto-fit pages" do?

From my experimenting with it, the answer appears to be "Diddly-squat".

Perhaps a better question would be "What is is supposed to do?"

Comment: I believe some phones (HTC?) made the distinction that when they have auto-fit (or some similarly named options) is disabled, then the browser will only reflow the text when double tapped (i.e. not when pinch-zooming); and while autofit (or that similarly named option) is enabled, then a pinch-zooming will reflow the text.

Comment: For people looking for a code fix for this issue, I've worked through it here: http://www.matt-helps.com/android-browser-auto-fit-fix

Comment: Chrome doesn't have this feature anymore: [Why doesn’t every browser do word wrapping?](http://pocketnow.com/2014/04/23/word-wrapping)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-fit is supposed to force the text to wrap based on the size of your screen when you zoom in on a web page.  I think.

As long as I'm connecting the right term with the right action, it has limits.  For instance, the page width doesn't actually change, and images and side bars won't change position, shape, or size.  Basically it's designed to keep you from scrolling sideways to read the text of an article.

Comment: OK.  Yeah, I can see that it does that... on some websites, anyway.

Comment: @mhenry1384 - Again, totally dependent on the idea that I'm not associating the term and action improperly.  :)